# passing parameters using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a bean class where i use annotation based configuration using

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Demo.class);
```

in my controller.

My demo class contains a method with parameter

```
public class Demo
{
public int method(int id)
{
//code
}
}
```

now how do i pass the parameter from the controller?

Comment: Share the annotations on Demo class.

Comment: create object of class and call the method.

Comment: i have shared annotations for demo class as Configuration and the method as Bean...but how to pass parameters from controller